# Count number of elements in mongo array with filter for specific documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple collection with documents of vendors that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Nick's Burger",
  "country": "AT",
  "branches": [
    {
      "branchId": "12535",
      "branchName": "Nick's Burger Branch One",
      "branchAddress": "Somewhere in austria"
    },
    {
      "branchId": "38267",
      "branchName": "Nick's Burger Branch Two",
      "branchAddress": "Somewhere else in austria"
    }
  ]
}
```

For each of the vendors there is a list of "branches", and I want to count how many branches all the vendors from "country"  `AT` have.

tried something like:

```
db.vendors.find({country: "AT"}, {$size: {branches: 1}}).count()
```

but that only gives me the count of vendors from AT...

Comment: From the marked duplicates, you can deduce the pipeline as `db.vendors.aggregate([ { '$match': { 'country': "AT" } }, { '$project': { 'branchesCount': { '$size': '$branches' } } } ])`

Comment: @chridam but I dont see there how can I get the sum of branchesCount...

Comment: @chridam my question was how to sum it up not how to print it with sum of each of the document array. i want to know sum of all arrays

Comment: Try `db.vendors.aggregate[{"$match":{"country":"AT"}},{"$group":{"_id":null,"branchesCount":{"$sum":{"$size":"$branches"}}}}])`

Comment: @Veeram thanks buddy, thats what i needed :)